# is it possible to have an System.Timer event check the progress of an object before firing?

Tags: c#, multithreading, animation, timer, console

I'm trying to make a simple game in C# for my little guy to play.

The class in my while loop sets the cursor position, changes background/foreground color, and writes a string. It also has a switch that moves the object on `ReadKey` left/right arrows.

The loop works perfectly, but when I try to add a second object it zips around the screen because of how fast the loop iterates. I cant use `Thread.Sleep` because it would effect the first object.

I created a `t.timer`, but I cant figure out how to prevent the timer event from firing off during the first object's methods. Unlike `System.Threading`, `System.Timer` don't seem to have a `Wait() method.

Here is my code, thank you for your help!

```
 bool _gameOver = false;
 SetScreenSettings();
 PlayerOne();
 Brick currentBricks = new Brick();

 int ballSpeed = 100;
 Timer t = new Timer();
 t.Interval = ballSpeed;
 t.Elapsed += BallThread;
 t.Start();

 while (!_gameOver)
 {
      Slider currentSliders = new Slider();   
 }
```

Comment: usually you want to have a gameloop that run on one thread then general UI on another thread, and in the game loop call a input function that read all keys then call the physics function that calculate and update all objects in the game then have a render function that's called last, and also use delta time to know how much time have passed since last update so you can do correct physics, you wound not have different threads for different objects.

Comment: @PatrikFröhler Excellent analysis! If OP wants to make a game using C# they should consider using Unity. It's free after all.

Comment: @PatrikFröhler thank you for your advice! I'll look into rearranging the logic, and using delta time. I'm still really new to programming, so some concepts are foreign to me.

Comment: @peacetype  The game will hopefully teach me the fundamentals before I move on to more advanced engines like Unity. The goal is to write this same game in console, windows universal, then unity. Thank you for comment.